# How to get Incoming and Outgoing Call's Number in Android 9 without READ_CALL_LOG Permission?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console, telephonymanager

I am developing Call Recorder app and in that app i need Incoming and Outgoing call's number to show the recording details in view.

it was working fine before android 9 but post android 9 we need to ask for two permission `READ_PHONE_STATE` and `READ_CALL_LOG` from user on runtime.

so that `brodcastReceiver` will triggered for 2 time. On first time we will get null from `intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)` and on second time we will get number. So we are handling it by checking `intent.hasExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)`

So scenario is when we don't use `READ_CALL_LOG` we will get null from `intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)` this problem is with `android 9`

I tried to release this app with this permission but app is getting rejected by `Google Play Console` because of this permission.

This app can be released by filling `Permission Declaration Form`. but i don't know how to fill that form so app get accepted by google.

So my question is how to get number without `READ_CALL_LOG` Permission. Any alternative of `TelephonyManager`? i've tried to get some alternatives but i didn't get. i've searched alot.

Or if Anybody knows how to release app with `READ_CALL_LOG` permission by filling `Permission Declaration Form` then please let me know.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Google only allows selected few use-cases to get the CALL_LOG permissions, and the call recorder use-case is not in that list.

Even worse, "call recorder" is explicitly mentioned under the "invalid uses" in the documentation: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?hl=en

So I'm afraid you can't get phone numbers for your app unless you release your app outside of Google Play.

Comment: hi @marmor, If i release application on **Amazon Appstore** so will i able to release app with `READ_CALL_LOG` permission.

Comment: you'll need to check Amazon's policies, but I'm not aware of a similar restriction it other app stores (amazon, samsung, etc.)